# Decrease query run time for reporting purpose

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following query takes about 58 minutes to run, I would like to optimize it to be more efficient. the weight_events table currently has about 1.5 million rows on it.

Tried adding index on the table but it doesn't change the query plan.

```
explain select round(sum(w1.current_sum_volume)::numeric / 1000, 3) as total
from bulk_lots b
join list_items bltype on bltype.id = b.list_item_id
join weight_events w1 on (
  w1.owner_type = 'BulkLot'
  and w1.owner_id = b.id
  and w1.created_at < '01-01-2019')
left join weight_events w2 on (
  w2.owner_type = 'BulkLot'
  and w2.owner_id = b.id
  and w2.created_at < '01-31-2019'
  and w2.created_at > w1.created_at)
where w2.id is null
  and bltype.name = 'Oil'
```

Indexes on table

```
  add_index "weight_events", ["bulk_lot_id"], name: "index_weight_events_on_bulk_lot_id", using: :btree
  add_index "weight_events", ["destroyed_id", "destroyed_type"], name: "index_weight_events_on_destroyed_id_and_destroyed_type", using: :btree
  add_index "weight_events", ["next_id"], name: "index_weight_events_on_next_id", using: :btree
  add_index "weight_events", ["owner_type", "owner_id"], name: "index_weight_events_on_owner_type_and_owner_id", using: :btree
  add_index "weight_events", ["previous_id"], name: "index_weight_events_on_previous_id", using: :btree
  add_index "weight_events", ["undoes_id"], name: "index_weight_events_on_undoes_id", using: :btree
```

Would expect a much quicker query time than 58minutes.

Comment: Please explain what you want this code to do.  I think there are better ways to write it.

Comment: Run ```EXPLAIN ANALYZE``` on query to see the bottle necks

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am trying to get the last records of a 1 to many relationship and sum up a column based on the last records.

Comment: @Philip . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and explain what you are trying to do.  If you can, simplify the query, so there are fewer tables.  You can include your current attempt as well and point out that you want a better performing approach.